# Difference between u2-scripts and universe basic code

Tags: u2, universe

What is the difference between U2 scripts and UniVerse Basic code in the UniVerse database?

Comment: Perhaps provide some context on what U2 is, besides a band?

Comment: Here's a little context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_U2

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by U2 scripts.  There isn't a scripting engine built in to U2 (Universe or UniData).  A U2 server can only run UniBasic programs, which are pre-compiled into object code.  You can, however, execute shell scripts from *within* a UniBasic program (see the `PCPERFORM` command).

Also, there are [client tools](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/tools/) available which let you access a U2 database and run native UniBasic code from other languages, such as C# and Java.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, ProVerb and Paragraph are both scripting languages which are included in UniVerse. You can get more information at: [u2ug.org](http://u2ug.org) or [u2data.com](http://u2data.com).

Answer (score 2):

The scripting languages in U2 are mostly relics from a time before the BASIC language had the EXECUTE command.  Essentially, this meant that you could not execute TCL commands from within BASIC programs, with the most important implication being that you could NOT generate SELECT lists with scope limiting criteria from within BASIC.

Consequently, any program that needed to access a criteria limited SELECT list need to be invoked with that SELECT list active.  In order to get the creation of such lists under programmatic control, a TCL scripting language was necessary.  Early incarnations of this were called PROC or ProVerb, and included some rudimentary flow control.  Many baroque nightmares of PROC were produced in the 70s and 80s, and were all were obsolete when the EXECUTE command was included in the BASIC language.

Nowadays, it's possible to work in a U2 system without knowing any PROC at all, and you'll rarely encounter a PROC that's more than a couple of commands long.

The Paragraph (PA) scripting language is something that came in from UniData.  It's simple and easy to read, and therefore beneath the dignity of experienced U2 programmers to use it.

Anyone want to talk about "F" correlatives now?